# Using a column as a list in where clause in a sql query

Tags: python, sql, plsql, apache-zeppelin

I created a list using a column a in python. I am trying to that in where clause in a sql query. list is a list of account numbers.

creating a list from the df

```
data1
acc_d1= data1['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']
t1 = tuple(acc_d1)
```

my code for sql query in python (I am using zeppelin)

```
sql="""
select id_number from table
where account_number IN {}""".format(t1)
prog_list_d1 = pd.read_sql(sql, dbc)
```

when I create a list by manually typing the numbers

```
acc_d1 = [12129530695080,12129530755769,12129516984649......]
t = tuple(acc_d1)

sql="""
select id_number from table
where account_number IN {}""".format(t)
prog_list_d1 = pd.read_sql(sql, dbc)
```

it works just fine. I am using python in a zeppelin notebook, and data is pulling from an Oracle database

Comment: try `t1 = acc_d1.tolist()` instead

Comment: @oskros negative. it does not work

Comment: what about `t1 = acc_d1.astype(int).tolist()` - and if that doesnt work, what is the error?

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column in the df was an object. By changing the column type to string before converting it to list worked. I kept everything else the same.

```
data4['account_number'] = data4['account_number'].astype(str)
prog_d4 = list(data4['account_number'])
prog_d4 = tuple(prog_d4)

sql="""
select account_number from table
where account_number IN {}""".format(prog_d4)
prog_list_d4 = pd.read_sql(sql, dbc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need parentheses around the list. I don't know Python but I would guess it would be simply:

```
sql="""
select id_number from table
where account_number IN ({})""".format(t)
```

And, by the way, really try to avoid this pattern. Varying length lists in IN clauses causes big problems for cursor sharing and is hard on the shared pool. Your DBA will not be happy if this happens with high frequency. It is far better to pull one account number at a time (with real bind variables, not string replacement), or if you need millions then load a temp table with the account numbers then use a join from there to your main table to get all the rows you want in one pull, without listing them in the SQL itself.

Comment: I don't think it should matter what is the length of the string I am trying to pass. The time complexity is lower, and automation is much easier simply by using the column provided rather than creating a temp table every time  I need to do this. The list have different lengths of account numbers, and it worked without parentheses!

Comment: It does matter. Varying length of IN lists are not sharable cursors. It will allocate a separate cursors in the shared pool for every different length, even if you use bind variables.  You might not care, but your DBA will.